# Selenium How to find element inside element

Tags: c#, selenium, browser-automation

Is it possible find element inside another element?
If we have html like this one

```html
<div> 
<span>Some text 1 </span>
<p>Other text 1</p>
</div>
<div> 
<span>Some text 2 </span>
<p>Other text 2</p>
</div>
<div> 
<span>Some text 2 </span>
<p>Other text 2</p>
</div>
```

is it possible to do something like this

```
IList<IWebElement> elements=driver.FindElements(By.TagName("div"));
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
   string text= elements[i].FindElement(By.TagName("span")).Text;
}
```

I have tried multiple times and in second iteration it is always finding me the the text from first element.

Comment: Which element / text exactly are you trying to find/locate? Did you notice the second and third `<div>` are identical? Does that matches your exact _usecase_?

Comment: So, what is the problem actually? Did you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

do you want to get `p` and `span` inside `div` ?

using `Xpath()` or `CssSelector()`

```
IList<IWebElement> div_childs = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div/*"));
// or
//IList<IWebElement> div_childs = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div *"));
foreach (var child in div_childs)
{
   string text = child.Text;
   string tag_name = child.TagName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS selector and let it do the work for you...

```
foreach (IWebElement element in Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div > span")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
}
```

This will find all SPANs that are children (>) of a DIV.